# Clickable icon for expanding/collapsing content

Tags: javascript, jquery, beginner

The general idea of the code is that I have a `+` or `-` icon (`".trigger"`) that is click-able and will expand or collapse the content (`".cont"`) directly following it (there are many of there expand/collapse pairs).  I also have a `span`(`"#expandAll"`) that, when clicked, will expand or collapse every block.

Please review my first usage of jQuery and help me put my head into a more jQuery state.  Where can the code be improved?  Are there any problems with it?  Is there a better way to do it?

(To be perfectly honest, I have no idea what the `$()` function *really* does.)

```
var expandAll = function () {
    $(".cont").removeClass("hid");
    $("#expandAll").html("Colapse All");
    $("#expandAll").unbind("click", expandAll);
    $(".trigger").html("-");
    $("#expandAll").click(colapseAll);
}
var colapseAll = function () {
    $(".cont").addClass("hid");
    $("#expandAll").html("Expand All");
    $("#expandAll").unbind("click", colapseAll);
    $(".trigger").html("+");
    $("#expandAll").click(expandAll);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".trigger").click(function (event) {
        $this = $(this);
        $this.html($this.text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
        $($this.nextAll(".cont").get(0)).toggleClass("hid");
    });
    $("#expandAll").click(expandAll);
});
```

Please let me know if you need more/less info.

Comment: @Jonathan, ha, nothing really.  It just seems that everyone these days starts 'programming' with html, css, and JQuery.

Comment: @zzz Yeah, I know, thanks.  I have fixed it in my code.

Comment: You should run your first jQuery in the Firebug Console.

Comment: "To be perfectly honest, I have no idea what the $() function really does." Don't worry, nobody knows everything it does. I've heard it can create world peace. [Hey, John Resig wrote it, right?](http://benalman.com/news/2009/12/john-resig-javascripts-chuck-norris/)

Comment: @alpha, haha that's good to know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've refactored your code and added comments to explain certain things.

```
// We can shorten this from document.ready(...) to $(...) 
// Internally, jQuery will add the passed in function to a list
// of handlers that will be invoked when the document is ready.
$(function() {
    // Since the $ function will query the document with the 
    // specified selector we want to cache these.
    // Doing this from within the ready callback allows us 
    // to keep these references hidden.
    // I've also added the 2 function variables to keep them
    // hidden as well.
    var expandAll, colapseAll,
        expandAllElement = $("#expandAll"),
        contElements = $(".cont"),
        triggerElements = $(".trigger");

    expandAll = function() {
        contElements.removeClass("hid");
        triggerElements.html("-");
        // Notice how we can chain these calls together?
        // jQuery was designed with a fluent interface.
        expandAllElement.html("Colapse All").one("click", colapseAll);
    };

    colapseAll = function() {
        contElements.addClass("hid");
        triggerElements.html("+");
        expandAllElement.html("Expand All").one("click", expandAll);
    };

    triggerElements.click(function(event) {
        // Always define a variable so the 'name' 
        // is not defined in the global object,
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.html($this.text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
        $($this.nextAll(".cont").get(0)).toggleClass("hid");
    });

    // Using the one function allows you to skip 
    // unbinding the event handler for each click.
    expandAllElement.one("click", expandAll);
});
```

Comment: Why do you declare `expandAll` and `colapseAll` outside of the `doc.ready()` function?

Comment: @Justin - You know I wasn't sure if you were manually calling those functions from other places. If your not using the functions anywhere else then that is definitely a good idea. See my latest changes.

Comment: Hm there's no need for making `expandAll` and `colapseAll` expressions, declarations would do just fine here. Also both functions are extremely similar in their workings, refactoring the code out into a more generic helper would be a good idea here.

Comment: OCD alert: `collapse` has two Ls (yes, I know the OP has the same typo).

Comment: @Matt, yeah I didn't notice that spelling fail until after I posted the code.  Didn't feel like fixing it.

Comment: For portability/extendability purposes you should use `jQuery(function($){});` to alias `jQuery` to `$` whether or not `noConflict` is called.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it was first and helped me make the most improvements.

Answer (score 3):

```
// If you use selectors multiple times, always cache them into variables, else jQuery has to search for them multiple times.
var $cont      = $('.cont'),
    $expandAll = $('#expandAll'),
    $trigger   = $('.trigger');

function expandAll() {
    $cont.removeClass('hid');
    $trigger.text('-');
    // Use .text() instead of .html().
    // You can chain these calls together.
    // If you use .one(), you don't have to unbind the previous event handler next time, jQuery does it for you.
    $expandAll.text('Collapse All').one('click', collapseAll);
}
function collapseAll() {
    $cont.addClass('hid');
    $trigger.text('-');
    $expandAll.text('Expand All').one('click', expandAll);
}

// You can pass a function to jQuery itself – it's a shorthand for $(document).ready().
$(function() {
    // There's no need to pass the event argument, because
    // 1. You didn't use it there
    // 2. jQuery “normalizes” the event object, so you don't have to pass it as an argument. If you want a shorthand for it, do it inside the function:
    // var e = event;
    $trigger.click(function() {
        // Always use var to declare variables, to prevent polluting the global scope.
        var $this = $(this);
        // Again: use .text() instead of .html().
        $this.text($this.text() == '+' ? '-' : '+');
        // There's no need to do this:
        // $($this.nextAll(".cont").get(0)).toggleClass("hid");
        // You can simply do this:
        $this.nextAll('.cont').toggleClass('hid');
    });
    $expandAll.one('click', expandAll);
});
```

Comment: One question, why do you use `html` and `text` in different scenarios?

Comment: `$this.nextAll('.cont:first').toggleClass('hid');` was what worked.

Comment: @Justin **1.** It was a mistake. Fixed. **2.** I don't get what are you trying to say…

Comment: the way my dom was `nextAll('.cont')` didn't work.  I needed to add the `:first`.  Not really important info for you.